# Given the relation $x^2-4x+y^2-4y+4=0$ determine the following... verify answers

Tags: derivatives

a) The equation of the secant line through the intercepts.

**For this part I got $y=-x+2$ as the equation of the secant line**

b) The slope of the curve at any point on the curve.

**Here I got $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x-2}{y-2}$**

c) The equation of the tanget to the curve where $x=4$

Here's  where I'm stuck, because when $x=4, y=2$ and if you plug in 2 for $y$ in the previous formula then you're dividing by 0.

Comment: The tangent line is vertical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculations are fine. As you point out, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ does not exist at $y=2$. Sometimes one says the slope is infinite there.

It may be useful to complete the square, getting $(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2=4$. This is a circle centre $(2,2)$, radius $2$. The tangent line at $x=4$ is vertical, so has equation $x=4$.

Comment: Interesting, thanks once again.